# How does correctly to use wp_signon?

Tags: wordpress

I make a custom form of authorization.
var_dump shows that the data from $ _POST is correctly passed, but why does not the redirect to the specified page work then? Help me to understand

my_authentification.php:

```
<?php   $my_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());  ?>
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://myreg_test_wordpress.loc/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/my_auth.php" method="post">
<div class="form-title "><h2>Authorization Form:</h2></div>
<label>Email: <br />
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" /></label>
<label>Password :<br />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" /></label>
<label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> remember</label>
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Войти" />

<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/my-temp-page-edit/" />
<input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url').'/my-temp-page/' ?>"><div class="my_btn">link to registration page</div></a>
</form>
```

my_auth.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );

if( is_user_logged_in() ) exit;


$my_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());

$user = wp_signon();
if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
echo $user->get_error_message();
//wp_redirect('http://myreg_test_wordpress.loc/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/my_authorization.php');
var_dump('my_authorization');

} else {

//wp_redirect('http://myreg_test_wordpress.loc/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/my_temp_page_edit.php');
var_dump('temp_page_edit');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alexandr. I can assume that you speak Russian. May be read russian documentation will be easier for you. [Check this link](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_signon) it is good translate for official docs.

Also in previous your qestion i gave answer how to do this.

> Create form, send on admin-post.php and create hook where you will
>   signon users and redirect where you’re need. Or use default WordPress
>   login page. Without custom form.

[admin-post.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) reference and usage examples. And not bad [guide](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/) how use admin-post.php in wordpress

Comment: yes, I speak russian. I used you link for documentation. But I have some problem. wp_signon don't redirect to <?php bloginfo('url') ?>/my-temp-page-edit/ after authorizated & writed errors on page my_auth.php, but should have moved to my_authentification.php and write errors here...

Comment: Why you use custom php file and custom including wordpress. Use admin-post.php for handle forms. And in end of file write wp_redirect(get_permalink('your page id'). All will work.

Comment: I must usage my file of authorization. I need to redirect to link which vardamping...But I don't know how I do it

Comment: Alex. Change action in form which i told. include your auth file in functions php file. In your file add actions with admin_post, dont load wp core manually. All will work. Your question - is a popular task.

Comment: I hope my answers helped you.

Comment: yes, thx, I have the problem, becouse i was var_dumping before wp-redirect

Answer (score -1):

my_auth.php don't use! I had the problem becouse I was var_dumping $user before wp_redirect. And wp_redirect  didn't work!

my_authentification.php:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['log'])) {

        $user = wp_signon();

        if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        $auth_error = 'Wrong auth data';
        } else {
            // DON'T war_dumping !!!!!!!!
        wp_redirect('/my-temp-page-edit');
        exit;
        }

        };
        get_header();
        ?>
        <?php   $my_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());  ?>
        <?php if (!$my_user->ID)  { ?>
            <form name="loginform" id="loginform"  method="post">
                <div class="form-title "><h2>Authorization Form: <span><?php echo $auth_error ?></span></h2></div>
                <label>Email: <br />
                    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" /></label>
                <label>Password :<br />
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" /></label>
                <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> Remember me</label>
                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Enter" />

                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/my-temp-page-edit/" />
                <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
            </form>
        <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Alexander. I gave instructions for handle forms. Use admin-post.php, nonces. your solution isn`t secure. Ia gave you link to wordpress developer official site, where you can read clean, wordpress oriented solutuions. create function, define two actions and create nonce field for your form. Check nonce, process your form and create redirect inside hooks.